# wicked_pdf: RuntimeError: (Failed to execute: Error: PDF could not be generated! Command Error: )

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

I've searched around on stackoverflow for other solutions and none of them seem to be the same as the specific issue I met.

We are using wicked_pdf and wkhtmltopdf-binary in a Ruby on Rails application. The code is failing on PDF export only for one particular person who has a significant amount of info compared to others in production (2 nodes) but works fine for others as well as in staging.

**Here are the logs we are getting:**

```
INFO: ***************WICKED***************
INFO:   Rendered application/_secondary_header.pdf.haml (3.1ms)
...
INFO:   Rendered application/show.pdf.haml within layouts/pdf (804.7ms)
INFO:   Rendered application/_primary_header.pdf.haml within layouts/pdf (151.8ms)
ERROR: Unable to fulfill your request RuntimeError(Failed to execute:\n"/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf" -q  --header-html "file:////tmp/wicked_header_pdf20140813-28740-auazsr.html" --footer-right "[page] of [topage]" --footer-font-size 9    --margin-top 30  --encoding "UTF-8"   "file:////tmp/wicked_pdf20140813-28740-1vmda5h.html" "/tmp/wicked_pdf_generated_file20140813-28740-1hzlru0.pdf" \nError: PDF could not be generated!\n Command Error: )
 vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/wicked_pdf-0.9.10/lib/wicked_pdf.rb:79:in `rescue in pdf_from_string'
 vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/wicked_pdf-0.9.10/lib/wicked_pdf.rb:83:in `pdf_from_string'
 vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/wicked_pdf-0.9.10/lib/wicked_pdf/pdf_helper.rb:64:in `make_pdf'
 vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/wicked_pdf-0.9.10/lib/wicked_pdf/pdf_helper.rb:78:in `make_and_send_pdf'
 vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/wicked_pdf-0.9.10/lib/wicked_pdf/pdf_helper.rb:21:in `render_with_wicked_pdf'
```

Code within application:

**controller.rb**

```
def show
  render pdf: file_name,
         layout: 'pdf',
         margin: {
           top: 30
         },
         header: {
           html: {
             template: '_primary_header.pdf.haml'
           }
         },
         footer: {
           right: I18n.t('pdf.page_description'),
           font_size: 9
         },
         encoding: 'UTF-8'
end
```

**System details:**

- Rails 4
- Ruby 2.1.0
- wicked_pdf 0.9.10
- wkhtmltopdf-binary 0.9.9.1

Note:

- This error log appears on both of the production nodes.
- It would be nice if someone can provide any assumptions on the cause of this issue.

Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: well what happens when you run `/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf" -q  --header-html "file:////tmp/wicked_header_pdf20140813-28740-auazsr.html" --footer-right "[page] of [topage]" --footer-font-size 9    --margin-top 30  --encoding "UTF-8"   "file:////tmp/wicked_pdf20140813-28740-1vmda5h.html" "/tmp/wicked_pdf_generated_file20140813-28740-1hzlru0.pdf"` on the production machine?

Comment: This is one limitation on my investigation. I'm not allowed to access the nodes and run the command there :( I'm looking for the possible assumptions for the cause of issue so that I can try to replicate it locally first.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated wkhtmltopdf-binary gem and everything worked fine.